# Extract or address each instance index

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say I have this simple setup of a Plane, instanced using a "Curve Line". I wanted to get the Index of each instance so I could use it down the line (i.e. pass it on later as the seed value) or pass it as an output of the geometry node. How do I do that or what node do I need to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple but not so obvious at first glance. You just use the *Index* node and plug it e.g. into a *Translate Instances* node. In my example I used it to move each instance a little further in X direction by plugging the index into a *Multiply* and *Combine XYZ* before the *Translate Instances*. Note that the index starts at 0.

[image: instance translation]

If you want to use it outside of the *Geometry Nodes* nodetree for example in a material you can use the *Index* node as well, although it's not working instantaneously. To make sure you get the index of the instances and not the points of all the planes you have to take a *Capture Attribute* node which you have plug in after the *Instance on Points* node.

Then you set it to *Integer* and *Instance* and plug the *Index* node into the *Value* input. To make it work now you cannot directly connect it to the *Group Output*, you have to add a *Realize Instances* node beforehand. I'm not sure why this is necessary, since the instances should have their index before realizing them.

Then you connect the *Attribute* output to the empty socket on the *Group Output* node and give it a name in the modifier. I called it "col_index" and added it with an *Attribute* node in the *Shader Editor*. I used a *Greater Than* node to drive the *Emission Strength* on the material.

[image: index color]

Of course you can combine both and create even more things with the index.

[image: index variations]

The *Capture Attribute* node is crucial to get the indices of the instances instead of those of the plane vertices. Since realizing instances seems to be necessary to transfer the attribute to the material, if you would capture the attribute **after** the *Realize Instances* node or plugging the *Index* node in the *Group Output* without capturing the attribute at all, this will result in the *Output Attribute* using the indices of the plane vertices.

For example, in the above image I used a 3x3 grid as plane, which makes 9 vertices per plane. In the *Spreadsheet* on the the left you can see, the value in the "col_index" column is 0 for vertices 0-8 (the first 9 of the first plane, instance 0), then the next values are 1 and so on. The *Greater Than* node has a threshold of 4.5, so the instances 0-4 are dark, the instances 5-8 have emission (the shine on instance 4 is a reflection).

The following image is to show the difference of not using a *Capture Attribute* node, I've set the grid to 9x9 vertices, resulting in 81 vertices per plane adding up to 810 vertices in total. As you can already see in the *Spreadsheet*, the "col_index" values are now 0, 1, 2, 3,... with each vertex having its individual index.

In the material this results in the emission no longer being turned on or off per plane, but per vertex. The *Greater Than* node has a *Threshold* of 343.5 which is far more than the number of planes, but not even half of the planes are glowing and the emission is only partial on the last of the glowing planes. The same would happen if you captured the attribute after realizing instances.

[image: index per vertex]

Comment: Wow! Very clear and you even went way beyond what I needed. Thanks so much! Not only did you answer my question, but you also provided a very clear explanation and other use cases. :D Thanks so much!

Comment: That capture attribute node always skips my mind. I've seen that before, but I forgot that it existed 

Comment: @Sophia At first I didn't use it either but it didn't work ;) And as I said, I have no idea why I have to realize instances, since the instances should have their indices without realizing them. I only know if you used the index on the realized instances without the capture attribute beforehand, the index of all the vertices will now be taken into account. Maybe I'll add this information to the answer.

Comment: in my version 3.3 alpha  it's even weirder. it works only if i set capture and output attribute to float....‍♂️

Comment: @Chris In my 3.3.0 Alpha it works with _Integer_...

Comment: maybe mac version problem....i have no idea

Comment: @Chris maybe because it's alpha ;) That's why I usually give answers with official releases. Some things might even change from alpha to final release.

Comment: of course they will change ;) that's what i expect. but i like to play and test the newest features ;) maybe i love the risk :D

Comment: @Chris Oh, I'm testing new things as well, but I won't base answers on them - only in the form of "not possible yet, but maybe in the future because this feature is already in alpha". For the same reason questions are usually closed if they are asking for something not working or missing etc. when it's regarding alpha or beta versions.

Comment: yeah, but this is one of the rules here...which i think - is ridiculous. Maybe make a flag to the question "it's an alpha version question" but to exclude those...that's one of the things i don't like about this site. So you can't ask question about new features as GN is....ok, now it's released but...yeah...but makes no sense to discuss it...that are the rules...i cannot change them...i just can use my time for other sites...which are much more free and open ;)

Comment: @Chris The problem with new features is, as long as it's no official release, whatever you are doing there and whatever solution you find might work in exactly that build, but can be different in any build before or after... even names or labels might be different. And I'm not talking about fully working features that are just waiting to be released, that's one thing. But everything that doesn't seem to work or exist might be there in the final build, so a question arousing on this might be just a temporary problem due to impatience and not waiting for it to be completed.

Comment: The same is true for different Blender versions…‍♂️

Comment: @Chris I guess, as a programmer I look differently at things like alpha, beta and final versions since it is a difference if you release something that's supposed to be a final working version and a work in progress. If someone tells me on a work in progress something's wrong I have that kind of disclaimer saying "yeah I know, never claimed it would all be working". In a final version things may be different than in previous versions, but supposed to be finished and working until they get an upgrade.